# How to add inline function info in dump_stack() of Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

Obviously, we can use dump_stack() in Linux Kernel to get the call stack information, but I found the inline function information is lacking in the output of dump_stack().

For example:
The call stack is:

```
 dont_mount include/linux/dcache.h:355 [inline]
 vfs_unlink+0x269/0x3b0
 do_unlinkat+0x28a/0x4d0
 __do_sys_unlink fs/namei.c:3945 [inline]
 __se_sys_unlink fs/namei.c:3943 [inline]
 __x64_sys_unlink+0x2c/0x30
 do_syscall_64+0x39/0x80
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

But through dump_stack(), I can only get this:

```
vfs_unlink+0x269/0x3b0
 do_unlinkat+0x28a/0x4d0
  __x64_sys_unlink+0x2c/0x30
 do_syscall_64+0x39/0x80
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

Obviously, inline functions are missing, when I look at the source code of the implementation of dump_stack(), seems the inline functions are not within the kernel_text_address().
Is there any way to get the ** call stack including the inline function calls **?

I tried to use compile option -fno-inline to disable inlining function, but then kernel failed to be compiled. Seems not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the [wiki definition](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-a-cpp-inline-function#:%7E:text=An%20inline%20function%20is%20a,the%20overhead%20of%20function%20calls.).

> An inline function is a function that is expanded inline when it is invoked, thus saving time. The compiler replaces the function call with the corresponding function code, which reduces the overhead of function calls.

So here is no "call stack including the inline function calls"

Comment: Any idea if I want to add this inline function call into the stack?

Comment: Change it from inline function to normal function is the easiest way.

Comment: I disable the inline at compiler end, but failed to compile, I will try translate the inline to normal, thanks.

Comment: I think this can work. Wheter it does work or not, please tell me. And if this anwer help you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me.